# How to grab all objects in a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like

```
 $(":input")
```

How do you return each object if there are multiple inputs? Maybe in somekind of array?

Also, is it possible to return the individual objects while using `$(":input").after(x)` ?

Comment: If by *"individual objects"* you meant the elements being inserted (as represented by `x`), then [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231489/how-to-grab-all-objects-in-a-selector/7231684#7231684).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**jQuery each**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$('input').each(function () {
    $(this); // A Single Input
})
```

Or

```
$('input')[0]; // HTMLElement Input
```

Alternatively, [jQuery's .get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

> supports a little more than [...], e.g. .get(-1) returns the last
>   element (which can be useful) - **pimvdb**

How to get length: `$('input').length`

Comment: jQuery's each does act like a loop,  yes

Comment: How about when using .after, guess i have to do .after on each object now instead of all at once?

Comment: And how do u know the total number of objects if you are using your second example ?

Comment: Note that `.get` supports a little more than `[..]`, e.g. `.get(-1)` returns the last element (which can be useful).

Comment: How about the question about .after?

Answer (score 1):

`$('input')`

will select all inputs

If you wanted to do something to them...

```
$('input').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background','red')
})
```

see this http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/RczBh/

Answer (score 1):

the jQuery factory function, `jQuery(...selector...)` or `$(...selector...)`, returns a `jQuery.init` object, which is essentially a fancy array of elements.

the [`each` function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is a simple way to continue to chain function calls while iterating through the entire selection of elements.

> The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.

The function parameter has two parameters `function( index, element )`, you could use `i` in place of `index` as it has the same basic effect. `this` will also refer to the `element`, so the second parameter is largely unnecessary unless you plan on executing a function within inner scope while retaining the reference to the element.

```
var vals=[];
$('input').each(function(index,element){
  var $this, val;
  $this = $(this);
  val = $this.val();
  vals.push(val);
  ...do more stuff...
});
console.log( vals );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":input")  // Returns a collection of DOM elements at 0-based indices wrapped
             //     in an object that contains jQuery methods

$(":input").length   // Is used to discover the quantity of elements matched.

$(":input").after('something')  // Implicitly applies .after() to each element.
                                //   Most jQuery methods work this way.

$(":input").each(function() {  // Lets you operate on each element individually.
    alert( this.nodeName );  // "this" will reference the current element.
});
```

---

> *"Also, is it possible to return the individual objects while using $(":input").after(x)"*

If you mean you want a collection of the resulting elements created by `.after()`, it will depend upon what `x` is.

If it's a single element (not a text node), just do this:

```
var new_elems = $(":input").after(x).next();
```

This places the new element after each `input`, then uses the [`next()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to traverse to the next element sibling of each `input`, which should be the new element that was inserted.